# Iterating in form of table in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to iterate the list in form of table. The following list should be rendered in the form of table using `*ngFor`:

I/p :

```
let list = [
  {
    "key1": {
      "subkey1": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        1
      ],
      "subkey2": [
        3,
        2,
        3,
        4
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "key2": {
      "subkey1": [
        1
      ],
      "subkey2": [
        0
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Table format (This is how table should render)  :

```
Categories | subkey1 | subkey2

key1       | 1,2,3,1 | 3,2,3,4

key2       |  1      |  0
```

I tried but its wrong :

Code I tried to iterate in component.html :

```
 <table border="1">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Categories</th>
              <th *ngFor="let each of categoriesHeading"> {{each}} </th>  // Array of subkeys
            </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody *ngFor="let each of categoriesList">
        <tr>
          <td *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(each)">// iterating keys
              {{key}} 
          </td>
          <td> </td> // I don't know how to itereate the values of each subkey of key [1,2,3]
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I was not able to share StackBlitz. So I'm sharing this screenshot :
[image]

Please let me know if something is missing.

Comment: Could you provide the code in a StackBlitz so it is easier to help?

Comment: Yes I'll try. 5mins

Comment: I have created StackBlitz, but not able to share it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can arrange the data as required and then display it in template.

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmpqyd?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Controller:

```
  categoriesHeading = [];
  displayData = [];

  constructor() {
    this.categoriesHeading = Object.keys(this.list[0].key1);

    this.list.forEach(item => {
      let obj = {};
      obj["key"] = Object.keys(item)[0];
      Object.keys(item[Object.keys(item)[0]]).forEach((subkey, i) => {
        obj[subkey] = item[Object.keys(item)[0]][subkey].join();
      });
      this.displayData.push(obj);
    });
  }
```

Template:

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Categories</th>
            <th *ngFor="let each of categoriesHeading"> {{each}} </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of displayData">
            <td *ngFor="let each of item | keyvalue"> {{each.value}} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> NOTE: For Angular 4, if you don't want to use (keyvalue pipe), then do the following.

TS:

```
objectKeys = Object.keys;
```

Template:

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Categories</th>
            <th *ngFor="let each of categoriesHeading"> {{each}} </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of displayData">
            <td *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(item)"> {{item[key]}} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Subkey's are hardcoded. There can be any no. of keys and subkeys

Comment: Ok, modifying the answer

Comment: Yes sure..  It will be helpful if you modify it.

Comment: Check the modified answer

Comment: No, only in  ts controller

Comment: there can be any no. of subkeys.. In html only 2 has been hardcoded

Comment: Oh, i forgot to modify it

Comment: Modified answer

Comment: @KedarKulkarni In the demo, I have added solution in both ways, using (keyvalue pipe as well aswithout using it). Check

Comment: Thank you so much .. can you explain me this ::=> 
 item[Object.keys(item)[0]]["subkey" +(i + 1)].join();

Comment: `item[Object.keys(item)[0]]` -> gets key1 property and `["subkey" +(i + 1)]` is the subkey property name, so basically it is `item.key1.subkey1` and join is used to convert array to comma separated string

Comment: What if the its not subkey... you have hardcoded subkey right?..But the thing is that subkey can be anything : xyz123 or qwe123 .

Comment: You should have clarified that earlier , it seemed it will be subkey1, sebkey2,... subkeyN

Comment: Modified the answer, it will simply be ` obj[subkey] = item[Object.keys(item)[0]][subkey].join();`

Answer (score 1):

While most of the given answers above are correct to the asked question, shall we see a better way to implement this example?

Before looking into better ways, let's see what needs to be improved in your example.

The first thing I see in your provided JSON is that you have hardcoded all the keys in here and if somehow those keys are updated later, then you have to update them in the frontend again. We can avoid that by using generic keys and keeping the labels you need in your table as values.

The next thing is you are adding some of the values in your table from your frontend code. It is good if the app is a static example, but it's recommended to fetch those records from a JSON so you have the freedom to change it as you wish.

Now let's see how you can improve this and get it working.

You can simply update your JSON as follows.

```
{
  "headers": [
    "Categories",
    "Sub Key 1",
    "Sub Key 2"
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "properties": [
        {
          "key": "Key 1",
          "key_data": []
        },
        {
          "key": "",
          "key_data": [
            1, 2, 3, 1
          ]
        },
        {
          "key": "",
          "key_data": [
            3, 2, 3, 4
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "properties": [
        {
          "key": "Key 2",
          "key_data": []
        },
        {
          "key": "",
          "key_data": [
            1
          ]
        },
        {
          "key": "",
          "key_data": [
            0
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I have done here is that you introduced some generic keys and took all the labels you want in your table as values.

You can use the following snippet to display the dataset as you requested in your web application.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let header of test_data.headers">{{header}}</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of test_data.data">
    <td *ngFor="let property of row.properties">{{property.key}}{{property.key_data}}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can find the working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/iterate-table-form

Hope this helps!

Good Luck!!

Comment: What if the JSON is from server and cannot be modified?

Comment: Then it's a poor way of the design. But in that case, there should be a modification done to the given data object in the frontend, processing it to work as static key-value pairs.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes the backend is already developed and there is nothing that can be done to it

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6onaoz) using the [KeyValue pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) introduced with Angular 6